# Magento 1.7 Costum option not working

Tags: php, magento

I have this weird problem out of the blue.

Magento was working find until today. The problem is this:
Now it is like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyKc0.jpg

How it looks after I remove the costum options in the admin panel:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMKLP.jpg

As you can see, it has something to do with the **Costum Product Option** it has nothing to do with the design, since I changed it back to the default template and that is the same deal. Also I don't use any stock feature what so ever(tested this and also has nothing to do with it)
Now I don't know how to debug this, since google chrome (debug console) isn't reporting any strange errors (non even). How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by removing magento completly and redoing every stap. Now I have 2 identical stores and 1 isn't working and 1 is, still a mistery. I guess it has something to do with the database, not sure what.